# Multi-column dependent countifs in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, count, countif, google-sheets-formula

Let's say I have 3 columns. I am trying to find the count of Zeros in the 3rd column IF column A is X AND column B is Y.

Is this possible? I've seen other people ask similar questions, but not seeing an answer anywhere. I know how to do the basic "if cell in column A is X, then count #-of-zeros in column B," but I don't know how to extend that dependency to an additional column.  I.e., If A is x, and if B is y, then count C.

Almost everything except the right answer.

```
=COUNTIFS('1H Run Values'!N:N,"0"&'1H Run Values'!T:T,"A",'1H Run Values'!S:S,"<=200")
```

does not work.

> n/a

Comment: also, clarify if you want to count two zeros in 200 too, or not

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, "=x", B:B, "=y", C:C, 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Annnd, that did it, hah. Simple. Thanks!